# batch if no key press continue (stopping a loop with a keypress)

Tags: batch-file, keypress

I wrote a simple script.  It is run through a compiler, and has a built in command featured by the compiler, so unless you download the compiler, or the raw file, you cant run it.  You should be able to figure out what I'm talking about though.

```
@echo off
set x=1
:loop
rem wait 5
cls
set /a x=%x% + 1
if %x%==20 goto loop2
rem shadeboxat 25 %x% 1 1 4
goto loop
:loop2
rem wait 5
cls
set  /a x=%x% - 1
if %x%==0 goto loop
rem shadeboxat 25 %x% 1 1 4
goto loop2
```

heres the advanced commands:

`rem wait 5`: all this does is wait 5 milliseconds.

`rem shadeboxat 25 %x% 1 1 4`: this creates a box at the coordinates 25 and %x%.  the `1 1 4` at the end are just extra info on what type of box I am creating.

I need some sort of method of adding a way to "jump to label if any key pressed".  unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.

I tried using the choice command, where I listed every regular key except one, and that one key was set as the default, with a timer of 1.  unfortunately 1 second is too much to wait.

I really doubt this is possible, but if anybody can prove me wrong, I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: You probably should just create a C-based console application for that. I'd prefer naming it as `wait_input.exe`. You can allow it to accept an option named `-t` that accepts a float number argument, or perhaps something similar to the arguments accepted by [sleep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sleep). The command would return nonzero if it reaches timeout without getting any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Batch but its a bit dodgy.

#### Main.bat

```
@echo off
set x=1
start /b KeyPress.Bat
wait 5
set /p end=< %temp%\keypress.tmp

:loop
wait 5
cls
set /a x+=1
set /p end=< %temp%\keypress.tmp
if "%end%"=="1" goto end
if %x%==20 goto loop2
shadeboxat 25 %x% 1 1 4
set /p end=< %temp%\keypress.tmp
if "%end%"=="1" goto end
goto loop


:loop2
wait 5
cls
set  /a x-=1
set /p end=< %temp%\keypress.tmp
if "%end%"=="1" goto end
if %x%==0 goto loop
shadeboxat 25 %x% 1 1 4
set /p end=< %temp%\keypress.tmp
if "%end%"=="1" goto end
goto loop2

:end
REM Program End Code
```

#### KeyPress.bat

```
@echo off
echo 0 > %temp%\keypress.tmp
choice /c 1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm /cs /n /M "Key Press To Cancel"
echo 1 > %temp%\keypress.tmp
Exit
```

This way, if any letter or number on the keyboard is pressed the program will exit prior to and change in a loop. That should be virtually instantaneous unless your `shadeboxat` takes a while to execute.

Other than that this should do what you want it to. Haven't got to testing it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In 32 bit Windows you can use a small .com file to detect a key like capslock or control etc being pressed, and branch on the errorlevel.